# Accessing integer variable in struct

Tags: c, struct

I have created a struct which stores an integer, and then in a method I set the integer to a value.  However, when I try to access the value in any other method, I'm given a large value that isn't the same.

```
typedef struct thing {
    int size;
    arraylist** list; // defined elsewhere
} thing;

// Creates a thing
void create (thing* table) {
    table = (thing *)malloc(sizeof(thing) * 8);
    table->size = 1;
    printf("%d", table->size); // prints 1
}

void another (thing* table) {
    printf("%d", table->size); // prints a large number
}

void main() {
    struct thing a;
    create(&a);
    printf("test: %d", (&a)->size); // prints a random large number, ex. 1667722352
    another(&a);
}
```

Comment: Why are you mallocing anything?

Comment: I don't think `size` is defined in `table = (thing *)malloc(sizeof(thing) * size);`

Comment: You allocate memory for what? `thing a;` (no need for struct) is on the stack, and you're trying to allocate memory for it in `create()`. Remove malloc line, and it may work.

Comment: And the `a` in `create(&a)` is not used.

Comment: I'm going to edit my original code version.  size was a variable I was using but removed for the sake of the example, and I am malloc-ing because it also includes an arraylist buffer.

Comment: Joseph, what do you mean by a in create(&a) is not used?

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you are saying.  I was using code example where the original struct was created on the heap, but in my code I'm creating it on the stack.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting a variable on the stack which giving you unexpected values later on.

In you're main function, you declare a `struct thing` on the stack.

```
void main() {
    struct thing a;  // Stack allocated variable
    create(&a);
    printf("test: %d", (&a)->size); // prints a random large number, ex. 1667722352
    another(&a);
}
```

All of the memory is already there, however you then take the address of the variable and pass that along to other functions.  Now, you pass that address (by value) to `create`, call `malloc` and replace that reference.  The address you've just assigned is not the address from the object on the stack.  And, because you haven't actually initialized the object on the stack, you end up printing out garbage values.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but one way to fix this exact instance is by not `malloc`ing new memory and just using what you have on the stack.

```
// Creates a thing
void create (thing* table) {
    // table already has memory
    table->size = 1;
    printf("%d", table->size); // prints 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was the result of ollowing an example online that doesn't match what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want another level of indirection:

```
typedef struct thing {
    int size;
} thing;

// Creates a thing
void create(thing **table) {
    *table = malloc(sizeof(thing) * size); // don't know what size is. 1?
    (*table)->size = 1;
    printf("%d", (*table)->size); // prints 1
}

void another(const thing *table) {
    printf("%d", table->size); // prints a large number
}

void main() {
    struct thing *a;
    create(&a);
    printf("test: %d", a->size); // prints a random large number, ex. 1667722352
    another(a);
}
```